# Уменьшение окна браузера - а контент?

Tags: вёрстка, css

Хэлло, вопросик возник. Видел сайты с резиновой версткой. Т.е. сжимаешь окно - естественно контент сжимается. Но до определенных размеров. Дальше контент не сужается, а кагбэ фиксированная ширина получается. Я этого достигал с помощью body {margin: 0 50px}, но на сайтах контент во всю ширину экрана. Как они ЭТО делают?

Comment: min-width?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте обертку:

```
<div class="wrapper" style="min-width: ; max-width: ;></div>
/*Стили, желательно прописывать в отдельном файле*/
```

правила CSS - **min-width** и **max-width**, задают минимальную ширину и максимальную - соответственно.

Answer (score 0):

Используй " % " вместо " px "

Comment: С % по-моему контент будет сжиматься до бесконечности. Посмотрите http://www.darkside.ru/ При изменении окна что происходит?

Comment: используй em, а не px